# Netcat listener: Line break between syslog messages

Tags: linux, syslog, netcat, udp

I am playing with `netcat` command. On this linux system, I have set up a netcat listener on UDP 514, so that I get to see syslog messages from remote systems.

```
$ sudo nc -v -ulp 514
listening on [::]:514 ...
connect to 192.168.20.252:514 from (null) ([::ffff:192.168.20.5]:58904)
<45>60: *Mar  5 19:57:06.735: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console<45>61: *Mar  5 19:57:32.651: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console<45>62: *Mar  5 20:10:10.127: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
```

The logs are coming through, but there is no line break between events. I need a line break between events. The terminal output is enough and no need to store the logs. While the logs are not uniform, how can I achieve this?

Comment: There's actually an RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424 Also. `netcat` is not the tool to use. Look at `sudo nc -v -ulp 514 | od -bc`..

Comment: Thank @waltinator. The od command gives me weird output. I have also noticed that I can receive well formatted logs from different systems (different OS). For example, the  unstructured logs in the question came from Cisco switch. But the Cisco ASA logs are coming through well formatted and structured

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do it with a one-liner, but a simple bash script can do the job. For me the following script is working:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]; 
do 
    nc -ulp 514 -w 0
    echo
done
```

Put it into `syslog-reader.sh`, make executable with `chmod a+x syslog-reader.sh` and run with `$ sudo syslog-reader.sh`.